# Why dict set same atfer loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a beginner in Python.

I  am retrieving data and saving it to dict. When looping on second time, it replaces my first key value.

You can find the output of second `Atfer match_chlDict`, the key `"1"` value is replaced by key `"2"`.

I have not way the fix it myself, please help. Thank you.

Here is the Original in match_details['chl']

```
[{'LINENUM': '1', 'LINESTATUS': '0', 'LINEORDER': '1', 'LINE': '9.5', 'H': '100@1.75', 'L': '100@1.95'}, {'LINENUM': '2', 'LINESTATUS': '1', 'LINEORDER': '2', 'LINE': '10.5', 'H': '100@2.20', 'L': '100@1.59'}]
```

the code

```
    match_chl={}
    match_chlDict={}
    for chl in match_details['chl']:          
        print("Current match_chlDict") 
        print(match_chlDict)
        match_chl['chlLINE']=chl['LINE']
        match_chl['chlH']=replace100(chl['H'])
        match_chl['chlL']=replace100(chl['L']) 
        #Write match_chl to dict by "LINENUM" as key                   
        match_chlDict[chl['LINENUM']]=match_chl    
        print("Atfer match_chlDict") 
        print(chl['LINENUM'])
        print(match_chlDict)
```

Output

```
Curr match_chlDict
{}
```

Atfer match_chlDict

```
1
{'1': {'chlLINE': '9.5', 'chlH': '1.75', 'chlL': '1.95'}}
```

Curr match_chlDict

```
{'1': {'chlLINE': '9.5', 'chlH': '1.75', 'chlL': '1.95'}}
```

Atfer match_chlDict

```
2
{'1': {'chlLINE': '10.5', 'chlH': '2.20', 'chlL': '1.59'}, '2': {'chlLINE': '10.5', 'chlH': '2.20', 'chlL': '1.59'}}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question!, so what's desired output?

Comment: please state your expected output. im not sure what youre asking

Comment: My expect return   for match_chlDict may be
{'1': {'chlLINE': '9.5', 'chlH': '1.75', 'chlL': '1.95'}, '2': {'chlLINE': '10.5', 'chlH': '2.20', 'chlL': '1.59'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReInitialise the `match_chl={}`every time in the loop or it will replace the reference in your dictionary.

```
match_chl = {}
match_chlDict = {}
for chl in m:
    print("Current match_chlDict")
    print(match_chlDict)
    match_chl['chlLINE'] = chl['LINE']
    match_chl['chlH'] = 'a'
    match_chl['chlL'] = 'b'
    match_chlDict[chl['LINENUM']] = match_chl
    print("Atfer match_chlDict")
    print(chl['LINENUM'])
    print(match_chlDict)
    match_chl = {}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: After reinitialize the match_chl , it work! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace100(str):
    return(str.replace("100@",""))

for chl in data:
    match_chl = {}
    match_chl['chlLINE'] = chl['LINE']
    match_chl['chlH'] = replace100(chl['H'])
    match_chl['chlL'] = replace100(chl['L'])
    match_chlDict[chl['LINENUM']] = match_chl
match_chlDict
```

Im not sure what youre looking for but i guess the code above works if you want to take the first element as key. I think maybe your error was that you stored the value in the same `match_chl`. you should reset its value each time the loop starts.